# Hangfire Database in Development Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, ef-core-2.1, hangfire-sql

I am using `Hangfire`in my ASP.NET Core application. It is still in development, now Every time I run the app I want `Hangfire` to delete the old Database and create a new Database for each run.

Currently when I Run the application the `Hangfire` Dashboard still shows old jobs even the ones that are no longer in my Code.

Is the something like below I can perform when configuring `Hangfire`

```
HangFirecontext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
HangFirecontext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to programatically remove the Hangfire tables. I think your best option is to drop the tables by executing regular SQL statements as soon as the application started. Hangfire will automatically re-create the tables for you. Alternatively, you can call [`SqlServerObjectsInstaller.Install()`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/ba2de549f00ac03bb21d45e86f705b067977c7ae/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/SqlServerObjectsInstaller.cs) (or the equivalent of another database provider) to re-create the tables right after you dropped them.